# xml schema for complex type with attribute

Tags: xml, web

I am trying to create xml schema for this element...

```
<shoesize country="yes">35</shoesize>
```

based on w3 schools this is solution....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="shoesize">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
       <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:string"  />
    </xs:extension>
   </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

what I am trying to restrict is that attribute can only be "yes" or "no" and content can only be integer less than 50. Can anyone give me some pointers how to do this please.

---

ok so i had made it work in separate file but when i put this code into my big schema within

```
<xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="something" type="xsd:string"/> 
        <xsd:element name="something else" type="xsd:string"/> 
        ......
        ......
        code above
        ....
        ...
</xsd:sequence>
```

i get error

```
s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'sequence' must match (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | any)*).
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in two stages, first define a named top-level `simpleType` to restrict the content (place this outside all your existing `xs:element` declarations, directly under `xs:schema`)

```
<xs:simpleType name="lessThanFifty">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
    <xs:maxExclusive value="50" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Then make your `complexType` extend this to add the attribute

```
<xs:element name="shoesize">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleContent>
   <xs:extension base="lessThanFifty">
    <xs:attribute name="country">
     <!-- you might want to pull this out into a top-level type if you
          have other yes/no attributes elsewhere in the schema -->
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:enumeration value="yes" />
       <xs:enumeration value="no" />
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
   </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This will allow any integer value up to and including 49, so `-500` is a valid value.  It may be more appropriate to start by restricting from `xs:nonNegativeInteger` instead of `xs:integer`.

Comment: I got 2 eerors when i tried to validate it...s4s-att-must-appear: Attribute 'name' must appear in element 'complexType'.
 and cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'shoesize'.

Comment: @Stribor edited to make it clearer that the named `simpleType` has to go at the top level of the schema, not inside your existing `sequence`.